# Error with Google Places Api (.addConnectionCallbacks)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, google-places-api

```
public class Places_DATA extends ActionBarActivity
{
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_places);


    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}
```

The problem is that I keep getting an error with the .addConnectionCallbacks(this). The error says the .ConnectionCallbacks cannot be added to the class. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I have been following google's documentation as seen here: https://developers.google.com/places/android/start

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use `this` unless it is `ConnectionCallbacks` and `OnConnectionFailedListener`. You can accomplish that by having your activity implement those interfaces.

```
public class Places_DATA extends ActionBarActivity
    implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_places);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // We are now connected!
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // We are not connected anymore!
    }

    @Override
    public onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // We tried to connect but failed!
    }
}
```